# discrepancy with Python datetime with timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone please help explain about the following. why don't I get even numbers for the hours?

I'm running Python 3.10. The following is from ptpython session:

```
>>> import pytz
... from datetime import datetime
...
... # Define time zones for Eastern Time and Pacific Time
... eastern_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
... pacific_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
...
... # Create datetime objects with accurate timezone offsets
... dt1 = datetime(2023, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=eastern_timezone) # Eastern Time
... dt2 = datetime(2023, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=pacific_timezone) # Pacific Time
...
... print(dt1)
... print(dt2)
2023-01-01 11:00:00-04:56
2023-01-01 08:00:00-07:53
>>> dt1 - dt2
datetime.timedelta(seconds=180)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assumed that a `pytz` value would be a suitable argument for the `tzinfo` parameter.  That's just not true.  If you print `eastern_timezone` or `pacific_timezone`, you'll see that's not true.

Do

```
import zoneinfo
eastern_timezone = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('US/Eastern')
pacific_timezone = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('US/Pacific')
```